# ASP Update Panel

Tags: asp.net

I implemented an **update panel** with a **treeview control inside**. The treeview control will cause a **postback via Javascript** which leads to the **OnNodeChecked** being triggered.

I have wrapped this in an UpdatePanel control, but I **still get the blinking effect** on my page. I also have a scriptManager implemented in the page. Does anyone know what I can do to avoid the flicker?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateTreeViewPanel" runat="server" 
                 ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <fieldset>
        <asp:TreeView ID="tv_WLG" runat="server"  
                      OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="tv_WLG_TreeNodeCheckChanged" 
                      OnSelectedNodeChanged="tv_WLG_SelectedNodeChanged" 
                      onclick="javascript:postBackByObject(event)"  
                      ShowCheckBoxes="All">
        </asp:TreeView>
    </fieldset>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Why are you handling the click event with javascript rather than the codebehind? I suspect that may be the issue.

Comment: @Ethan, the js fires a postback which fires the code behind. Which property in the Treeviewcontrol should be set to fire the code behind?

Comment: Are you just triggering a random postback or do you actually want something to happen?

Comment: when the parent node is selected, then all child nodes are selected, that is what the postback is handling.

Comment: What server-side event are you using to handle this after the postback?

Comment: And what next? At some point, the state of the tree view is persisted to the database? You could handle the checking of child nbodes via javascript/jquery - fixing the pages refresh issue in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend adding a trigger...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...your existing code
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tv_WLG" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The clientside script you're targeting may occur outside the scope of the update panel however. You might try handleing your click event in the codebehind instead.

Comment: Won't `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` obviate the need for explicit trigger?

Comment: Still get postback after stripping out ChildrenAsTriggers.

Comment: In you JS, try running some jquery to select children of the node that fired the event. http://api.jquery.com/children/ Let me know if you need help with getting those children. This should remove the need to post back, thereby resolving the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add an `onload` event to the updatepanel and trigger that using `__doPostback()` like so.  Then whenever the click event fires you can handle it in the onload event of the updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateTreeViewPanel" runat="server" 
                 ChildrenAsTriggers="true" OnLoad="UpdatePanel_Load" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <fieldset>
        <asp:TreeView ID="tv_WLG" runat="server"  
                      OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="tv_WLG_TreeNodeCheckChanged" 
                      OnSelectedNodeChanged="tv_WLG_SelectedNodeChanged" 
                      onclick="__doPostback('updateTreeViewPanel', '');"  
                      ShowCheckBoxes="All">
        </asp:TreeView>
    </fieldset>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The reason your current method isn't working is because the postback object needs to be an object that is being handled by the update panel.  Calling `doPostback()` with the update panel as the object will trigger the partial postback.